# Member Variable in Header Undefined

Tags: c++, header-files, member

I'm trying to learn how to split my code up into header and source files, but don't understand why my member variable `attackPower` is considered undefined.

Enemy.h

```
#pragma once

class Enemy{
protected:
    int attackPower;
public:
    Enemy();
    void setAttackPower(int a);
    virtual void attack() = 0;
};
```

Enemy.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Enemy.h"

class Enemy {
public:
    Enemy::Enemy(){
        attackPower = 0;
    }
    void Enemy::setAttackPower(int a){
        attackPower = a;
    }
};
```

In Enemy.cpp, Visual Studio tells me

> identifier "attackPower" is undefined

Comment: You have 2 different Enemy classes.

Answer (score 1):

Your cpp file shouldn't redefine the whole class. Instead of

```
class Enemy {
public:
    Enemy::Enemy(){
        attackPower = 0;
    }
    void Enemy::setAttackPower(int a){
        attackPower = a;
    }
};
```

You should just have

```
Enemy::Enemy(){
    attackPower = 0;
}

void Enemy::setAttackPower(int a){
    attackPower = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're defining implementations they should not be inside a `class` definition:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Enemy.h"

Enemy::Enemy() {
    attackPower = 0;
}

void Enemy::setAttackPower(int a) {
    attackPower = a;
}
```

A better way of defining your constructor is this:

```
Enemy::Enemy() : attackPower(0) {
}
```

You should also get in the habit of flagging arguments as `const` unless you absolutely need to mutate them:

```
void Enemy::setAttackPower(const int a) {
    attackPower = a;
}
```

Comment: `const int a` is unnecessary because top-level const modifiers are ignored in a parameter